# tablesorter data-math-filter returns no results when given a valid css selector

Tags: tablesorter

I'm using Mottie's tablesorter plugin with the Math extension. I have a conditionally formatted table - the categories of conditional formatting are indicated in a data-color attribute on the data cell.

In the footer, I have several rows that summarize the values of the conditional formatting. The footer cells are decorated with data-math-filter="[data-color='color1']".

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-color='red' style='background-color:red'>
        3
      </td>
      <td data-color='blue' style='background-color:blue'>
        7
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-color='green' style='background-color:green'>
        6
      </td>
      <td data-color='red' style='background-color:red'>
        4
      </td>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td data-math-filter='[data-color="red"]' data-math='col-sum'></td>
      <td data-math-filter='[data-color="red"]' data-math='col-sum'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-math-filter='[data-color="green"]' data-math='col-sum'></td>
      <td data-math-filter='[data-color="green"]' data-math='col-sum'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-math-filter='[data-color="blue"]' data-math='col-sum'></td>
      <td data-math-filter='[data-color="blue"]' data-math='col-sum'></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

My reading of the docs leads me to believe that the math function will filter for the data-elements - but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried a bunch of different CSS filters - nothing seems to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `data-math-filter` supposed to do? And in the last `td` in the `tfoot`, I see a `style='` with only one single quote... that's probably breaking stuff

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'm looking at the documentation: https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-math.html

Realizing you may not have ever touched this widget in your fork. Anyway - the data-math-filter is supposed to allow you to filter in/out cells based on an attribute or selector. If you go to the docs above, then Options > math_rowFilter - you'll see the docs for this piece.

Thanks!